# Why am I getting the following error and what should I have in the empty constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, compiler-errors, abstract-class

I have an abstract class, TwoDPolygon.

```
abstract class TwoDPolygon
{
double width, height;
String name;

public TwoDPolygon()
{
width = 0;
height = 0;
name = null;
}

public TwoDPolygon(double width, double height, String name)
{
this.width = width;
this. height = height;
this.name = name;
}

public TwoDPolygon(double equalWidthHeight, String name)
{
width = equalWidthHeight;
height = equalWidthHeight;
name = name;
}

public String getName()
{
return name;
} 

abstract double area();
}
```

A sub-class, Triangle, that extends TwoDPolygon.

```
public class Triangle extends TwoDPolygon
{

String status;

public Triangle()
{
super();
}

public Triangle(String status, double width, double height)
{
this.status = status;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
}

public Triangle(double size)
{

}

public String getStatus()
{
if ("filled".equals(status))
status = "filled";
if ("notFilled".equals(status))
status = "notFilled";
return status;
}

double area()
{
return (1/2)*(width)*(height); 
}
}
```

And a main method, which was provided to me. The other two classes I was to write myself given the main method and some instructions.

```
public class Ex2Driver
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
TwoDPolygon polygons[] = new TwoDPolygon[3];
polygons[0] = new Triangle("filled", 8.5, 12.0);
polygons[1] = new Triangle("not Filled", 6.5, 7.5);
polygons[2] = new Triangle(7.0);

for (int i=0; i<polygons.length; i++)
{
System.out.println("Object is " + polygons[i].getName());
System.out.println("Triangle " + polygons[i].getStatus());
System.out.println("Area is " + polygons[i].area());
}
}
}
```

I realize that the third constructor in my Triangle class is empty. I know it is supposed to be there, from instructions, but I am stuck on what to put inside it. Regardless of that, I am getting a "cannot find symbol" error from the driver class the line

```
System.out.println("Triangle " + polygons[i].getStatus());
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you do not call the super in all of your constructors. you must do so.

instead of:

```
public Triangle(String status, double width, double height)
{
this.status = status;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
}

public Triangle(double size)
{

}
```

do this:

```
public Triangle(String status, double width, double height)
{
super(width, height, status);
this.status = status;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
}

public Triangle(double size)
{
super(size, null);
}
```

**EDIT #1**

Also arrays only carry methods that are of the class it is, even if you add an object that inharets that class, you lose access to the methods in the subclass.
you should use arraylists, those carry the methods even if the super class does not have them. so it should look like this:

```
ArrayList<TwoDPolygons> polygons = new ArrayList<TwoDPolygon>(3);
polygons.add(new Triangle("filled", 8.5, 12.0));
polygons.add(new Triangle("not Filled", 6.5, 7.5));
polygons.add(new Triangle(7.0));

for (int i=0; i<polygons.size(); i++)
{
System.out.println("Object is " + polygons.get(i).getName());
System.out.println("Triangle " + polygons.get(i).getStatus());
System.out.println("Area is " + polygons.get(i).area());
}
```

**EDIT #2**
if you can not modify the `Ex2Driver`then in your `TwoDPolygon` class just add an abstract method for getStatus like `abstract String getStatus();`, that should solve the issue of calling methods.

now for getting null for the name, that is because in the Triangle constructers when i put the super calls i put null for the name, you can change that to "Triangle" like this:

```
public Triangle(String status, double width, double height)
{
super(width, height, "Triangle");
this.status = status;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
}

public Triangle(double size)
{
super(size, "Triangle");
}
```

also in your `TwoDPolygon(double equalWidthHeight, String name)` constructer you do `name = name;` that just sets your temporary variable name equal to it's self, you should do `this.name = name`.

Make sure to set the name in every constructor so that you do not get null when running it. in the triangle constructor you do `name = "Triangle";`, but in the TwoDPolygon constructors do `name = "TwoDPolygon";` so if you ever make more sub class' you can see if you forget to set the name, and it looks nicer that way.

In your area method, make sure to do `return (0.5 * width * height);` that should fix the issue of getting `0.0`.

In all of your Triangle constructors that do not have status as a parameter make sure to do `status = "filled";` or `status = "notFilled";` so that you do not get `null` in your answer.

Hope this helped :D

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. I called super in the Triangle constructors. But unfortunately, I don't have the option to use ArrayList instead of Array, as the main method was provided by my instructor. But when I run the program, my output is all "0" and "null". Any idea why this might be?

Comment: I modified my answer take a look at EDIT #2

Answer (score 1):

Because the type of polygons[] is TwoDPolygon `TwoDPolygon polygons[] = new TwoDPolygon[3];`, it searches for the method getStatus() in the class declaration of TwoDPolygon, not Triangle, even though the elements are instantiated as Triangle.

You have several options to fix this:

1. change the declaration to Triangle

   `Triangle polygons[] = new Triangle[3];`
2. move the getStatus method to TwoDPolygon
3. cast the object to Triangle in each loop

   `System.out.println("Triangle " + ((Triangle)polygons[i]).getStatus());`

Comment: This was very helpful. I moved getStatus to the TwoDPolygon class, which fixed all my compile time errors. I also called super in the Triangle constructors, like someone else suggested. But when I run the program, my output is all "0" and "null". Any idea why this might be?

Comment: The output is 0 because of the way you wrote the calculation `return (1/2)*(width)*(height);` 1 / 2 is evaluated as an integer division, which results in 0. To fix this, `return (1.0/2)*(width)*(height);` to make java do a float division. As for getName() and getStatus() returning null, check that you actually supplied values for them when instantiating the object. I notice that you didn't supply any status when calling the constructor for the third triangle element

Answer (score 0):

You initialized array polygons as

```
TwoDPolygon polygons[] = new TwoDPolygon[3];
```

Yet when you access the elements from the array, you are calling a method in subclass Triangle.  You can't call a Triangle-only method from a TwoDPolygon.

Initialize the array as Triangle elements or move getStatus() to class TwoDPolygon.